# parse_url giving host name as stars when debugged (but can still get value)

Tags: php, cakephp

*Using PHP 5.5.12*

*Using CakePHP 2.6.7*

Running

```
debug($url); // output = "http://google.co.uk"

debug(parse_url($url));
/* output = array(
                'host' => '*****',
                'scheme' => 'http'
            )
*/
```

I had been using this without trouble but now copy/pasting a section of my code to have it as method (to save repeating myself) has started giving me this output. But testing it back in the same place I had it originally gives me this output too.

Can anyone explain why the hostname is stars and why the rest of the array doesn't appear (I realise all other elements should be expected to be NULL)?

**Edit**

Just tried it again with a url that had a path to a page after the host. The path shows up fine but the host is still starred out.

**Partial Answer**

Just thought to try `debug(parse_url($url)['host'])` and it prints the host correctly. I realised that the other elements would only be set if they exist in the url.

However, can anyone explain why printing out the array prints several stars instead of the hostname even though it is definitely stored there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because of how debug() works. Many moons ago people were not pleased that they could accidentally have their database credentials dumped out in error pages (which use the same underlying code as `debug()`). Because of this, debug() and Debugger::export() blacklist a set of array keys that *could* have database credentials.  The following keys are replaced with ***'s:

- password
- login
- host
- database
- port
- prefix
- schema

Comment: Hadn't occurred to me that `debug()` might do that, I just assumed it was like an easier to read alternative to `var_dump()`. Thanks